Weird Line-Breaking and Left-Alignment on Glossary
Following this answer by @Tom, I was able to improve my glossary quite a bit, but it still has some weird behaviors. For example, the terms appear to be justified, instead of left-aligned, and sometimes there is a comfortable line-break, and at other times, there's no line-breaking at all:

I think that comes from the glossaries package using the longtable package, but I have no idea of how to fix these things.
Even if I don't choose a very small width for the main definition text, the weird line-breaking still happens:

Here's an MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

% ~A6 (+ 5mm min left and right offset)
\usepackage[%
  paperheight   = 148mm, 
  paperwidth    = 105mm,
  bindingoffset = 8mm,
  left          = 5mm,
  right         = 8mm,
  top           = 15.2mm,
  bottom        = 13.2mm,
  footskip      = 6.35mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
% From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730599/64441).
\newglossarystyle{tableStyle}{
  \setglossarystyle{long}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {\begin{longtable}{p{1.5cm}p{6cm}}}
    {\end{longtable}}
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\glswrglosslocationtextfmt}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\delimR}{$\boldsymbol{-}$}
\renewcommand{\delimN}{{\bfseries, }}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{atari}{
  name        = atari,
  description = {Quando 1 ou mais pedras estão com somente 1 liberdade, isto é, estão prestes a serem capturadas. Também é o termo que deu o nome ao respectivo console de videogames}
}

\newglossaryentry{boca-de-tigre}{
  name        = boca-de-tigre,
  description = {Forma de três pedras geralmente utilizada para eficiente criar uma conexão}
}

\newglossaryentry{casco de tartaruga}{
  name        = casco de tartaruga,
  description = {O número mínimo de pedras para se capturar um grupo de 2 pedras advesárias. Assim como o ponnuki, é uma forma extremamente forte}
}

\newglossaryentry{crane's nest}{
  name        = crane's nest,
  description = {``Ninho do grou'' é um problema famoso de rede}
}

\newglossaryentry{dan}{
  name        = dan,
  description = {Equivalente de mestre ou faixa-preta no Go e muitos outros esportes. E, na verdade, o termo faixa-preta foi inspirado pelo Go. Para amadores, utiliza-se a abreviação ``d'', e.g. ``5d''; e, para profissionais, a abreviação ``p'', e.g. ``7p''}
}

\newglossaryentry{dumpling}{
  name        = dumpling,
  description = {``Dango'' em japonês, ``bolinho chinês'', ``cacho de uva'' em coreano, é a denominação para um amontoado de pedras, que geralmente possui poucas liberdades e faz pouco território}
}

\begin{document}
  \glsaddall
  \printglossary[
    title    = Glossário,
    toctitle = Glossário,
    style = tableStyle,
  ]
\end{document}


The example here didn't load package hyperref. The commands need to be changed as I mentioned in the previous answer. note that package hyperref must be loaded before package glossaries.

To me that the 1.5cm text width is too small. Latex have a hard time to find the correct line break. And note that - in word will force a line break. This make the case even worse. If you want the text to be left justified, you need explicitly set that in column specifier. You could load package array and add >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} in front of p{1.5cm}

True, @Tom. Thanks!

it's not that glossaries uses longtable. it's that you are choosing that particular style and then modifying it so the results cannot be anything but ugly. the original answer used 3cm, you'd originally suggested 5. you have a text block only 84mm wide. depending on font and content, that may already be somewhat challenging. you have to think about whether your chosen style is appropriate for that page layout and that content. that said, you are not giving tex any chance at all here because you aren't loading either babel or polyglossia. so it use the minimum american hyphenation.

@cfr Ok, cool, I didn't know my dimensions were that egregious. But anyways, it's what I got, since my book is on A6 paper. If I add babel, which I do use on my project, what would be the minimum dimensions for it not be anything but ugly? And I didn't know about the polyglossia package, I've only been using babel for Portuguese.

Btw, even with wider dimensions, the weird line-breaking is still happening. (See the edit)

@psygo I didn't see weird line-breaking from your new edits.

@Tom Maybe I misused the term, I mean that there's a line between most definitions, but some don't, e.g. between the "atari" and "auto-atari" ones.

that's because the entries are grouped i.e. a break between the 'a's and 'b's.

@cfr :O I didn't know it did that. Apparently, there's an option called nogroupskip which takes out the skip. But what I wanted was for there to be a skip between every term, and for term text to be like regular text in that if it doesn't fit the page, it continues on the next one, instead jumping down to the next page. But I guess that might be difficult to do with a table, I don't know.

@psygo you cannot break a cell in a longtable. so, if you use this style of glossary, entries cannot be broken across pages. you can alter the skip between entries by adjusting the separation between rows. see the array package documentation, for example. that's a straightforward tweak. but if some entries are long, you will end up most likely with empty space at the bottom of pages. if some entries are very long and don't fit onto a single page, they will overrun the page boundaries. so it really depends on the variety of entries you have. this style is OK if they're all pretty short.

@cfr Do you know if there's a way of having table-like alignment without longtable? All I want is some sort of alignment across all words, without the jagged alignment that comes with glossaries by default. And having a skip between the terms also makes it look much nicer.

use a custom list, maybe? with a set label width. no table cell can break across pages as far as I know. (but I don't know tabularray well.)

A custom list could do I guess, as long as terms are each a paragraph like regular text. Do you have a tip as to how I could do it? I could create a new question, if you prefer. I'm really surprised by these limitations on tables, long tables seem to be quite the common use case.

The default glossaries style doesn't have any alphabetical grouping apparently, now that I came back to it. And it's pretty close to what I wanted actually. I think I'm gonna stick to it in the end.
